# Is there a way to add html element as footer and header in jsPdf for each page?

Tags: jspdf

I am trying to add footer and header for each page using jsPDF. I can include text but I need to include HTML elements like table or list or image to the footer and header.

Note: I tried with auto-table but since the content of the pdf is from the html page (i.e., contains list, text, etc.,) it is not suitable for my scenario.

Can anyone suggest a way to implement the same?

Thanks in advance.